# --React does update the size of the containing div when it is populated by new content

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I populate my web app with JSON data but the containing div does not expand as is should.

I don't think React is aware that the div should expand.  Here is a screens hot of the offending div.

Note all the parent divs including the body tag have heights of 100%.  I can post any code needed.

[image]

**Relevant CSS**

```
/* FRAME
**
**
*/


html{
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
body{
  height:  100%;
  width: 100%;
}
#app{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#contents{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
#top-1{
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-top: 3px solid #000000;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbbbbb;
  z-index: 1000;
}
#top-2{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px dotted #888888;
  border-right: 1px dotted #888888;
}
#container-1{
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 44px;
}
#container-2{
  position: relative;
  width: 90%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px dotted #888888;
  border-right: 1px dotted #888888;
}
.body{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: remove `height:100%` that is keeping your div from expanding.

Comment: because you have set height:100% on the container (the one you want to grow), it is stuck at 100% of the height of it's parent. Since you have set `height:100%` all the way up, each of your elements are stuck at 100% of the height of the window.

Comment: try using `min-height:100%` on your container div instead of `height:100%` that way it is always at least 100% of the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of a `css` issue rather than a `react` thing.
You didn't post any code so it's kind of hard to be sure what is going in on there.
But in general, `block` and `inline-block` element will expend as their content grows by default (unless you take their children out of the flow with `float` for example).
Here is  a small example:

```js
const Item = ({ name }) => {
  return (
    <div className="item">
      <div className="item-name">{`Item - ${name}`}</div>
      <div>{`This is just another line for item ${name}`}</div>
    </div>
  );
}

const List = ({ items }) => {
  return (
    <div className="list">
      {
        items.map(o => {
          return <Item name={o} />
        })
      }
    </div>
  );
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      items: [1, 2, 3]
    };
  }

  addItem = () => {
    const {items} = this.state;
    const nextItem = items.length + 1;
    const nextState = [...items, nextItem];
    this.setState({items: nextState});

  }

  render() {
    const { items } = this.state;
    return (
      <div className="main">
        <button onClick={this.addItem}>Add</button>
        <List items={items} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```css
button{
  padding: 5px 20px;
  font-size: 1.1em;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-color: #4285f4;
  border:none;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #333;
  color: #fff;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

.main{
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  display: inline-block;
}


.item{
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px 1px #ccc;
  padding: 15px;
  margin: 10px 5px; 
  display: inline-block;
  width: 20%;
}

.item-name{
  margin: 5px 0;
  font-size: 1.2em;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #34a853;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: +1 this is definitely a CSS issue. React isn't even responsible for the height of the div unless you explicitly set it with `style={...}`.

Comment: Was this answer helped you achieve your result?